# Does the convex hull of a sphere contain every point on its surface?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis

Sorry if this is an obvious question but I have not been able to find a straightforward answer for it.
My intuition tells me this is correct, and have confirmed that the scipy convex hull algorithm will return all samples used to generate a Fibonacci sphere as hull vertices.

I am not a math person, but a coder trying to test the performance scaling of a script, so if someone could confirm this (with a proof if you're feeling generous) I would much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: The convex hull of a convex set is the set itself.

Comment: thanks, i suppose it is that simple, and maybe was simply looking for a proof of why a sphere is a convex set..

Comment: or rather, why a sphere is the bounding surface of the convex ball

Comment: The convex hull of a set $Q$ is defined as the smallest convex set containing $Q$, so what you want should follow by definition.

Comment: Are your spheres hollow or solid?  It matters here.  To most mathematicians sphere implies hollow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall these two pertinent facts about the norm/length function:
\begin{align*}
\|x + y\| &\le \|x\| + \|y\| \\
\|\lambda x\| &= |\lambda| \|x\|,
\end{align*}
where $x$ and $y$ are vectors and $\lambda$ is a scalar.

The unit ball is defined by $\{x : \|x\| \le 1\}$. Suppose $x$ and $y$ lie in this ball. We wish to show that the line segment between $x$ and $y$, i.e. all points of the form $\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y$ where $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, also lies in the ball. We have,
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y\| &\le \|\lambda x\| + \|(1 - \lambda)y\| \\
&=|\lambda| \|x\| + |1 - \lambda|\|y\| \\
&\le |\lambda| + |1 - \lambda|
\end{align*}
When $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, then $\lambda, 1 - \lambda \ge 0$, so
$$\|\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y\| \le \lambda + 1 - \lambda = 1,$$
which is what we wanted to show.